# Pass the path if user upload the image from input type=file else pass img src path.

Tags: php, html, css

I need to handle if user upload the image from input type=file then pass the path otherwise pass img src path.

How?

```html
<div class="thumb thumb-rounded thumb-slide">
  <img src="<?php echo $result['staff_signature'];?>" alt="Signature IS BLANK">

  <div class="caption">
    <input type="file" class="file-input" data-show-caption="false" data- show-upload="false" accept="image/*" id="signature" name="signature">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement?

Comment: please share relevant code and explain better your problem

Comment: If u want to know how to upload file by using PHP,  check this for ref - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: What do u mean by ```pass the path otherwise pass img src path``` ?

Comment: This is actually code of profile picture update. First fall, i show image in <img src="path read from mysql"> And i wants to pass same path if user dont replace image by using <input type="file"> and if use <input type="file"> then pass path of uploaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understand from ur question i think u need this..

```
<div class="thumb thumb-rounded thumb-slide">
      <img src="<?php echo $result['staff_signature'];?>" alt="Signature IS BLANK">

      <div class="caption">
        <input type="file" class="file-input" data-show-caption="false" data- show-upload="false" accept="image/*" id="signature" name="signature">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="imgsrc" id="imgsrc" value="<?php echo $result['staff_signature'];?>">
```

upload section

```
    if($_FILES[signature]['name']!="")
        {
    //file upload code
        }
    else
    {
    $imgsrc=$_POST['imgsrc'];
//get the imgsrc value using GET/POST ..whatever u are using the form

    }
```

Let me know your feedback

Comment: Thank you so much .

Answer (score 1):

You can upload user files to the server with AJAX from a form with  field, but if you want to be nice to the user and show a preview, you HAVE to do the round trip and upload the file to the server first

Comment: This is actually code of profile picture update. First fall, i show image in <img src="path read from mysql"> And i wants to pass same path if user dont replace image by using <input type="file"> and if use <input type="file"> then pass path of uploaded image.